# How to manage different php.ini settings in production and development?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration

Is there a best practice for managing php.ini configurations from development to production?  Obviously it can be done manually, but that is prone to human error. I'd like to try and have the production file in version control and then possibly modify the development version automatically.
Thoughts or ideas i've had which i dont know if they are feasible:

1. php.ini includes - just include the dev settings at the end of
   the file?
2. conditional loads from apache conf?
3. write a script that when php.ini changes, a dynamic version of phpdev.ini gets generated - (i know this can be done)
4. use runtime php settings for display errors - i think this has limitations because if the script has fatal errors, then it wont run the runtime setting.
5. backup plan - keep the production version in SC, and manually change
   phpdev.ini as needed as needed.  Then if manual mistakes are made
   they are done at the development level.

Comment: What is your application deployment process?  Specifically, when you deploy your app, are you deploying code or the whole tech stack?

Comment: I think i might need some best practices on that also.  Ideally i want to make it automated / fool proof (if there is such a thing).  Currently the deployment is hack/custom db upgrade script, and svn update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Store your ini in your source code repository in different directories named after their environments: environments/{dev,qa,staging,prod}/php.ini
2. On each environment, do this:  `rm /etc/php.ini; ln -s /var/www/site/environments/prod/php.ini /etc/php.ini`

This way, you get the benefits of revision control and don't necessarily have to edit each manually.

Comment: This seems like the quickest way to accomplish what i want.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad it's helping. Don't forget to vote up answers you accept.

Comment: I was thinking a bit more about this, and im still wondering what prevents making a change in the development version that gets tested, but then the production version is not updated with the appropriate change?  This could cause problems in the application when moved to production environment.

Comment: if you're really anal, make it so that the PHP.ini file cannot be modified by anyone other than root.  Your hypothetical problem is one of change management; nothing can really shield an organization from its lack or users going cowboy on the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is what you're looking for, but personally I like to perform all non-security-necessary php.ini modifications via the apache virtualhost settings, e.g. a development virtualhost:

```
    ServerName sb.local
    ServerAlias sb.local
    DocumentRoot /srv/some-site

    php_value session.cookie_domain "sb.local"
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
php_value mbstring.func_overload 7
php_value default_charset "utf-8"
AddDefaultCharset utf-8 

php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "990000"
php_value error_reporting 30711
# 30711 = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE
php_value display_errors "On"
php_value display_startup_errors "On"
php_value log_errors "On"
php_value html_errors "On"
```

etc