# php ini settings for error reporting

Tags: php, php-ini

I am running my website on VPS. I can create 1 instance for LAMP. I want to set different settings for error reporting on development server and production server.

Is there any way to define two different settings for development and production in same php.ini file?

I want to set

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

for development server, and

```
error_reporting(0);
```

for production server.

Comment: And how would php know it is a development or production server when reading the ini file?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure it out. I know there is a way to do it. But, I don't know how?

Comment: You can apply that configuration on **apache** site rather than php.ini... That way you can have two sets of configuration (2 sites) in apache and you basically turn one off and another - on

Comment: can we create two settings of apache in VPS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage different php.ini settings in production and development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963003/how-to-manage-different-php-ini-settings-in-production-and-development)

Comment: VPS is a server.. Virtual Private, but a Server nonetheless ;) And Apache allows multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two sets of configuration inside the same `php.ini` file.
But you can have multiple **sites** in `Apache`.

In each of those sites you can configure environment-dependent settings.

For example, in `prod.conf`:

```
php_value error_reporting 0
```

And, in `dev.conf`:

```
php_value error_reporing -1
```

You can also throw in other stuff like `display_errors` and `error_log` definitions like that.
Then, you switch on `prod.conf` site on production server, and `dev.conf` on the development one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly in the php.ini. There are a few ways you can accomplish what you want:

- You could use settings directly in the Apache vhost conf to explicitly set the desired values for that vhost.
- You could use directives in a [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only) file, one for your live app and one for your dev app.
- You could use an environment variable to trigger your app to set the right settings. In the Apache config or .htaccess, set an environment variable like "APP_MODE" to "development" or "production". Then your application code can look for that var and set the reporting accordingly. E.g., `if (getenv('APP_MODE') == 'development') { error_reporting(E_ALL); }`
- You could use a framework that does this for you. Zend Framework for example uses a combination of environment variable and ini file.

Comment: When I am trying to edit .htaccess file, it's giving me internal server error. I have defined AllowOverride All in httpd.conf file for my project directory. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps a syntax error or misspelling? What exactly are you putting in the file? Perhaps a permissions error? Make sure the file is readable by the user that Apache runs under.

Comment: `<Directory "/home/website/public_html">
        Options All MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from </Directory>`

Comment: and .htaccess file's permission is: 644

Comment: The .htaccess should exist at the top level of the site you want to affect (i.e., the document_root) and contain `php_value error_reporting 0` -- or whatever value you want to set it to.

Comment: ERROR LOG says: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration